# Is there a MANOVA test on circular variables?

Tags: manova, circular-statistics

I have a population 4 individuals moving in different directions in 9 different compartments. The movement is not coherent between the different compartments, but I suspect that it is coherent between individuals within each compartment. However, the low number of individuals does not provide much power in testing the movement direction in each compartment. Thus I would like to test whether the individuals move in the same direction in across the whole data set. In a non-circular setting I think that a MANOVA could solve this, but I don't know how to test this on circular data. Anyone knows how to do this?
Thanks
Martin

Comment: There is no MANOVA yet for circular data. Maybe you can resort to chance capitalization correction? Power may become an issue, but you can try.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What do you mean by chance capitalization correction?

Comment: That would be something like running all the tests, then performing a Bonferroni like method (such as the FDR, false discovery rate method) to ensure you don't inflate your type 1 error.